# Extracting a portion of values from a Dataframe.

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to write a function to select a portion of a Dataframe such that: 
given in input the "first_non_zero_index" (in our case the index of the row ) and a value threshold (e.g 4), return the index, called "last_non_zero_index", such that df.loc[first_non_zero_index:last_index] will produce the output result. Moreover, between two no-zeros values are permitted only up to 10 consecutive zeros.

I would be very grateful for your help. Much appreciated. 
Many Thanks in advance.
Carlo

Input Dataframe:

```
id, ts,value,
id1,2017-04-27 01:35:30,0
id1,2017-04-27 01:36:30,0
id1,2017-04-27 01:37:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 01:38:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 01:39:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 01:40:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 01:41:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 01:42:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 01:43:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 01:44:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 01:45:30,4.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:46:00,99.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:47:30,100.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:48:30,100.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:49:30,100.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:50:30,100.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:51:30,100.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:52:00,100.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:53:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 01:54:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:55:30,5.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:56:00,6.0  
id1,2017-04-27 02:57:30,7.0 
id1,2017-04-27 02:58:00,8.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:59:30,4.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:00:30,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:01:30,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:02:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:03:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:04:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:05:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:06:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:07:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:08:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:09:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:10:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:11:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:12:30,4.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:13:00,99.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:14:30,1000.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:15:30,1000.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:16:30,1000.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:17:30,1000.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:18:30,1000.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:19:00,1000.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:20:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:20:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:21:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:22:30,5.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:23:00,6.0  
id1,2017-04-27 02:24:30,7.0 
id1,2017-04-27 02:25:00,8.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:26:30,4.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:27:30,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:28:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:29:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:30:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:31:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:32:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:33:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:34:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:35:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:36:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:37:00,0
```

Output Dataframe:

```
id, ts,value,
id1,2017-04-27 01:45:30,4.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:46:00,99.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:47:30,100.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:48:30,100.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:49:30,100.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:50:30,100.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:51:30,100.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:52:00,100.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:53:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 01:54:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 02:55:30,5.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:56:00,6.0  
id1,2017-04-27 02:57:30,7.0 
id1,2017-04-27 02:58:00,8.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:59:30,4.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you on the right track.  It will take the input DataFrame and return an output DataFrame that goes from the first element that passes your 'threshold' to the last element that passes it.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

def extractPartialDataframe(df, threshold):
    indicesList = df[df.value >= threshold].index.tolist()
    new_df = df.iloc[min(indicesList): max(indicesList) + 1]
    new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    return new_df

trimmedDF = extractPartialDataframe(df, 4)
maxConsecutiveZeros = 10
consecutives = trimmedDF["value"].groupby((trimmedDF["value"]!=trimmedDF["value"].shift(1)).cumsum()).transform('count')

tooManyConsecutiveZeros = trimmedDF[(trimmedDF["value"] == 0)&( consecutives > maxConsecutiveZeros)].index.tolist()
final_df = trimmedDF.iloc[:tooManyConsecutiveZeros[0]]
print (final_df)
```

---

```
OUTPUT

10  id1  2017-04-27 01:45:30    4.0
11  id1  2017-04-27 01:46:00   99.0
12  id1  2017-04-27 01:47:30  100.0
13  id1  2017-04-27 01:48:30  100.0
14  id1  2017-04-27 01:49:30  100.0
15  id1  2017-04-27 01:50:30  100.0
16  id1  2017-04-27 01:51:30  100.0
17  id1  2017-04-27 01:52:00  100.0
18  id1  2017-04-27 01:53:00    0.0
19  id1  2017-04-27 01:54:00    0.0
20  id1  2017-04-27 02:55:30    5.0
21  id1  2017-04-27 02:56:00    6.0
22  id1  2017-04-27 02:57:30    7.0
23  id1  2017-04-27 02:58:00    8.0
24  id1  2017-04-27 02:59:30    4.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much AustinOB. What is not clear to me is how to select the zeros values between (e.g. row 18 and 19 ) two no-zero values?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  The zero values are included in the output because indicesList includes all values [10, 11, ..., 23, 24].  It does not include 18 and 19, but the slice of the original DataFrame is returned from index 10-24. 

 If you are asking how to access those rows, you can take the returned dataframe, and do something like returnedDF[returnedDF.value == 0]

Comment: OK. But, it means that the indicesList would include also the indexes of many other rows e.g. <id1,2017-04-27 02:14:30,1000.0, id1,2017-04-27 02:15:30,1000.0, etc>. right? If YES, this is not what I am looking for, as it would include sequences of values containing any number of consecutive zeros. I only want those that contains no more that 10.

Comment: The solution you provided  is very close to the one I implemented. What I have difficulties with is selecting only the right one that satisfies the property that I expressed above.

Comment: I did run your solution and it does what I said. It is not CORRECT.

Comment: Edited solution, should address the 'more than 10 consecutive zeros' issue now.

Comment: I am checking it.,...1 min

Comment: Thanks AustinOB. Unfortunately, your solution does not address the problem completely. All you code can be rewritten in very few line of codes, such as:  `threshold = 4`                                                                                                          
`consecutives = df["value"].groupby((df["value"]!=df["value"].shift(1)).cumsum()).transform('count')
series = df[(df["value"]!=0)|(consecutives<threshold)]    
print(series)`

Comment: Thanks AustinOB. Unfortunately, your solution does not address the problem completely. All you code can be rewritten in very few lines of code, such as:  `threshold = 4`                                                                                                          
`consecutives = df["value"].groupby((df["value"]!=df["value"].shift(1)).cumsum()).transform('count')
series = df[(df["value"]!=0)|(consecutives<threshold)]    
print(series)` . What I need is to take only the first segment as I specified at the beginning.

Comment: Many Thanks @AustinOB. It is working. Many Thanks. Very appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153806/discussion-between-austinob-and-carlo-allocca).

Answer (score 0):

I guess by threshold you mean a delimiter (threshold may suggest a `>=` or `<=` operation and by the desired output I think you want `==` because there are lines with values both lower and higher than 4 in your example).

Find the first non zero value:

```
start = (df['value'] != 0).tolist().index(True)
```

Find the delimiters (4.0 in your example):

```
fours = (df['value'] == 4).tolist()
```

Slice by the first non zero to the first delimiter after the first non zero:

```
df.iloc[start:fours.index(True, start+1)+1]
```

Output should be like your example:

```
         id                   ts  value
    10  id1  2017-04-27 01:45:30    4.0
    11  id1  2017-04-27 01:46:00   99.0
    12  id1  2017-04-27 01:47:30  100.0
    13  id1  2017-04-27 01:48:30  100.0
    14  id1  2017-04-27 01:49:30  100.0
    15  id1  2017-04-27 01:50:30  100.0
    16  id1  2017-04-27 01:51:30  100.0
    17  id1  2017-04-27 01:52:00  100.0
    18  id1  2017-04-27 01:53:00    0.0
    19  id1  2017-04-27 01:54:00    0.0
    20  id1  2017-04-27 02:55:30    5.0
    21  id1  2017-04-27 02:56:00    6.0
    22  id1  2017-04-27 02:57:30    7.0
    23  id1  2017-04-27 02:58:00    8.0
    24  id1  2017-04-27 02:59:30    4.0
```

[update]

I don't know how if there is a pandas equivalent for this list comprehension but perhaps it can inspire you:

```
valid = [df['value'][i:i+10].sum() >= 4 for i in range(len(df))]

df.iloc[start:valid.index(True, start+1)]
```

The above is not exactly what you asked, it will stop at the first 10 consecutive values less than four. Strictly what you asked is more like this:

```
valid = [bool(df['value'][i:i+10].sum()) or value >= 4 
         for i, value in enumerate(df['value'])]
```

If the performance is not terrible using this may be better than keep banging your head in order to find a "pure pandas" method.

Comment: first of all, thank you very much for your answer. Well, what I mean by a threshold is a value which identify the the sequence of values that  I need. In the particular case of setting threshold=4 means that: I want the sequence that "start" with a value>=threshold and "end" with a value<=threshold, but it could also have up to 10 consecutive zeros.

Comment: what I am finding hard to implement is how to tell that the sequence should not stop at the first or second, third,...ten, zeros if after that there value >= 4.

Comment: I think there is no elegant way to do this other than iterating over all lines - but someone smarter than me may came up with a solution.

Comment: Paulo Thanks again. I am trying very hard to get it. I am sure we can make it. You solution is helping me to look at the entire problem from another prospective. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks AustinOB. Unfortunately, your solution does not address the problem completely. All you code can be rewritten in very few line of codes, such as:  `threshold = 4`                                                                                                          
`consecutives = df["value"].groupby((df["value"]!=df["value"].shift(1)).cumsum()).transform('count')
series = df[(df["value"]!=0)|(consecutives<threshold)]    
print(series)` . What I need is to take only the first segment as I specified at the beginning.